# Is there a way to ignore(like a private "mute"), a participant in Zoom so that you don't hear them. If you don't run the room?

Tags: zoom-meeting

Is there a way to ignore(like a private "mute") a participant in Zoom so that you don't hear them. (If you don't run the room). I don't mean like actual muting.. but like an ignore.

I know that if you run a room you could mute somebody so that nobody hears them.

But i'm asking re if I don't run a room and i'm just looking to personally not hear them, not to stop others from hearing them. So an ignore option rather than a mute option. I know you can't mute somebody if you don't run a room.

Is an ignore like I mention possible? (like a private "mute")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You, the user, can mute only ourself. You cannot mute others (that is turn others' sound off or privately ignore them) in Zoom (only the host can do that) or even ignore them in Zoom just for you.

The only control you have is your own overall sound control

The Host can mute everyone and unmute everyone (or invdiduals).

There is a bit of noise where, if I mute myself, and then the Host mutes everyone, I may have to unmute myself when the Host unmutes "everyone".  It just means we have to watch our own mute icon.

Comment: well i'm not exactly asking about muting somebody in the normal sense, but about making it so that I don't hear them. Like putting somebody on ignore. I'll make my question clearer

Comment: There is no way in Zoom to mute a single person (except the host). The only control use have is your overall volume control .

Comment: ok thanks, can you clarify your answer by rewriting the word "mute" 'cos I don't actually mean mute in the sense most would understand it.

Comment: I have clarified my answer for you and trust that helps.